# Subsetting a data.frame using a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

Assume a user wants to subset 7 rows after some row number.

The output should be this

```
iris[4:10,]
```

But subsetting is done based on a variable begin_row

```
begin_row=4
iris[begin_row:begin_row+6,]
#iris[c(begin_row:begin_row+6),] also this does not work
```

Why is the output not the 7 rows as the desired output? How is it done correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing parenthesis here:

```
iris[begin_row:(begin_row+6),]
```

The operator precidence of <kbd>`:`</kbd> is higher than plus <kbd>`+`</kbd>

A quick `?Syntax` or `help(Syntax)` can tell you that